# Exposing a service endpoint from within an Office Add-In

Tags: web-services, office365, office-addins, office-js

I am trying to create an [Office Add-In](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/overview/office-add-ins) whose functionality is similar to one of the samples for PowerPoint: [enter link description here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/officeapps/2013/06/10/create-a-web-service-for-an-app-for-office-using-the-asp-net-web-api).

```
----------                          -----------
| Add-In | =======================> | Service |
----------                          -----------
```

#### Service in the add-in

The main difference with the tutorial is that I want to reverse the approach: I want to expose a service endpoint inside the add-in and call it from some other application (it would be an HTTP binding reachable over TCP-IP).

```
--------------------------          -----------
| Add-In || Service:port | <======= | Process |
--------------------------          -----------
```

Is this possible?

#### Alternatives

I searched a bit, but it seems like the API are not including components to define services. This kinda seems reasonable as a whole hosting environment would be needed.

However, we are talking about Javascript API, so I was hoping that maybe [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) could be used. My point here is to be able to contact the add-in from outside avoiding the add-in to poll for messages to a whatever service endpoint.

What options do I have to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Client side JavaScript can't host a service.

Your server side code can do whatever you want, and you can definitely use WebSockets to communicate with the add in.